# Card.io calling onActivityResult too soon?

Tags: android, card.io

I just put a simple card.io 3.03 implementation into my Android app, but soon as I launch the CardIOActivity I immediately get my onActivityResult called, with null data and a resultCode of 0 (RESULT_CANCELLED).  After onActivityResult is called, then the card.io activity is displayed and I can take a photo normally.  But after the card is successfully photographed and read, onActivityResult is not called again so I can't pass the card number back into my app.
I am supplying the app token, and I'm fairly confident I haven't done this wrong, as I am able to see scan metrics on the card.io website.

Here is what I'm using to launch card.io:
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this, CardIOActivity.class);

```
    // required for authentication with card.io
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_APP_TOKEN, CARDIO_APP_TOKEN);

    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true);
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false);
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_ZIP, false);

    startActivityForResult(scanIntent, DemoAppConfig.SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Where is this code being called? A common mistake is to put in your own onCreate(). Also, does the example app (https://github.com/card-io/android-scan-demo) work for you?

Comment: Is your issue have been solved?

Comment: I'm not calling from onCreate().  I call from a button listener, just like the demo app.  I just tried the demo app, and yes it's working perfectly!  I can't find a difference in what the demo app code and my own, but will update this page if I find a solution.

Comment: Has this been solved? If not, any hints in the logcat? (Also note that card.io has been updated since this question was originally asked.)